# rearrange and grouping

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xml file that needs to modified by grouping elements in new nodes.
Each occurence of the elements in the `<account_plan>` , the `<account_service>` and `<account_option>` nodes must be grouped in the new node `<account_info_total_list>`
Hereafter is an example input xml. I can only use XSLT 1.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Invoice>
<account_info>
<acct_id>12345678</acct_id>
<account_meta_data_info>
  <doc_id>100009999</doc_id>
</account_meta_data_info>
<account_plan>
  <Plans>Plan1</Plans>
  <Amount_plan>1x</Amount_plan>
  <Price_VATinclude_plan>12.10</Price_VATinclude_plan>
  <Price_VATexclude_plan>10.00</Price_VATexclude_plan>
</account_plan>
<account_plan>
  <Plans>Plan2</Plans>
  <Amount_plan>2x</Amount_plan>
  <Price_VATinclude_plan>24.20</Price_VATinclude_plan>
  <Price_VATexclude_plan>20.00</Price_VATexclude_plan>
</account_plan>
<account_service>
  <service_name>service1</service_name>
  <Amount_service>1x</Amount_service>
  <Price_VATinclude_service>12.10</Price_VATinclude_service>
  <Price_VATexclude_service>10.00</Price_VATexclude_service>
</account_service>
<account_service>
  <service_name>service2</service_name>
  <Amount_service>2x</Amount_service>
  <Price_VATinclude_service>24.20</Price_VATinclude_service>
  <Price_VATexclude_service>20.00</Price_VATexclude_service>
</account_service>
<account_option>
  <Price_VATexclude_option>10.00</Price_VATexclude_option>
  <Options>Option1</Options>
  <Amount_option>1x</Amount_option>
  <Price_VATinclude_option>12.10</Price_VATinclude_option>
</account_option>
<account_option>
  <Price_VATexclude_option>20.00</Price_VATexclude_option>
  <Options>Option2</Options>
  <Amount_option>2x</Amount_option>
  <Price_VATinclude_option>24.20</Price_VATinclude_option>
</account_option>
<account_option>
  <Price_VATexclude_option>30.00</Price_VATexclude_option>
  <Options>Option3</Options>
  <Amount_option>3x</Amount_option>
  <Price_VATinclude_option>0.72</Price_VATinclude_option>
</account_option>
<subs_base_info>
    <subscription_number>671880401</subscription_number>
    <charge_excludeVAT>63.73</charge_excludeVAT>
    <charge_includeVAT>73.29</charge_includeVAT>
    <tariff_plan>EU 4G Flat XXL(SOHO)</tariff_plan>
 </subs_base_info>
<subs_overview_info>
    <billing_cycle_his1>01/2014</billing_cycle_his1>
<subs_overview_info>
</account_info>
</Invoice>
```

> The output must be as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Invoice>
<account_info>
<acct_id>12345678</acct_id>
<account_meta_data_info>
  <doc_id>100009999</doc_id>
</account_meta_data_info>
<account_info_total_list>
  <Plans>Plan1</Plans>
  <service_name>service1</service_name>
  <Options>Option1</Options>
  <Amount_plan>1x</Amount_plan>
  <Amount_service>1x</Amount_service>
  <Amount_option>1x</Amount_option>
  <Price_VATinclude_plan>12.10</Price_VATinclude_plan>
  <Price_VATinclude_service>12.10</Price_VATinclude_service>
  <Price_VATinclude_option>12.10</Price_VATinclude_option>
  <Price_VATexclude_plan>10.00</Price_VATexclude_plan>
  <Price_VATexclude_service>10.00</Price_VATexclude_service>
  <Price_VATexclude_option>10.00</Price_VATexclude_option>
</account_info_total_list>
<account_info_total_list>
  <Plans>Plan2</Plans>
  <service_name>service2</service_name>
  <Options>Option2</Options>
  <Amount_plan>2x</Amount_plan>
  <Amount_service>2x</Amount_service>
  <Amount_option>2x</Amount_option>
  <Price_VATinclude_plan>24.20</Price_VATinclude_plan>
  <Price_VATinclude_service>24.20</Price_VATinclude_service>
  <Price_VATinclude_option>24.20</Price_VATinclude_option>
  <Price_VATexclude_plan>20.00</Price_VATexclude_plan>
  <Price_VATexclude_service>20.00</Price_VATexclude_service>
  <Price_VATexclude_option>20.00</Price_VATexclude_option>
</account_info_total_list>
<account_info_total_list>
  <Price_VATexclude_option>30.00</Price_VATexclude_option>
  <Options>Option3</Options>
  <Amount_option>3x</Amount_option>
  <Price_VATinclude_option>36.30</Price_VATinclude_option>
</account_info_total_list>
<subs_base_info>
    <subscription_number>671880401</subscription_number>
    <charge_excludeVAT>63.73</charge_excludeVAT>
    <charge_includeVAT>73.29</charge_includeVAT>
    <tariff_plan>EU 4G Flat XXL(SOHO)</tariff_plan>
 </subs_base_info>
<subs_overview_info>
    <billing_cycle_his1>01/2014</billing_cycle_his1>
<subs_overview_info>
</account_info>
</Invoice>
```

Is it possible to do this with xslt 1.0?

This is what I just tested, but is not working, where do I go wrong?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="account_info">
<xsl:apply-templates select="acct_id | account_meta_data_info"/>
<xsl:call-template name="aggregate"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="aggregate">
<xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
<xsl:if test="$i &lt;= count(account_plan) or 
$i &lt;= count(account_service) or $i &lt;= count(account_option)">
    <account_info_total_list>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="account_plan[$i] | account_service[$i] | account_option[$i]"/>
    </account_info_total_list>
    <xsl:call-template name="aggregate">
        <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="account_plan | account_service | account_option">
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="account_info">
<xsl:apply-templates select="subs_base_info| subs_overview_info"/>
<xsl:call-template name="test"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="test">
    <xsl:call-template name="test">
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes", if you show us what you've tried so far and explain what you're having trouble with then we might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Yes that's possible. But there are hundreds of answers on XSLT 1.0 grouping on Stackoverflow already - and you did obviously not take the time to search for them.

Comment: This is what I tried so for for one of the lines, but the logic is not working as expected.

Comment: What are the rules for grouping? It looks like you want to group **account_plan_info_consume** elements into **account_consume**, but I can't see what links them in each group. Also, in your input XML you have "Nokia Test1" and "Nokia Test2", but in your output they seem to become "Samsung Galaxy Test1" and "Samsung Galaxy Test2". Maybe just a typo...? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed the input to make it more clearer (I renamed some elements in each node). The elements of the nodes <account_plan_info_consume> , <account_service_info_consume> and <account_option_info_consume> must be grouped in the node <account_consume>. As a result the 7 nodes are grouped in 3 nodes, each containing all elements.

Comment: I have made the example a bit easier I hope. Until now I did not find simular examples. The question is also: Is this file suitable for making the transformation, is there sufficient structure?

Comment: What connects Plan1 to Service1 and Option1 (other then their position in the document order)? Will there **always** be the same number of each?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have to group the first occurence of each of them in the first new node <account_info_total_list>, then the second occurence in the second new node <account_info_total_list>.

Comment: So basically, in order to know how many occurrences of  `<account_info_total_list>` there will be, you need to count each of the three and take the maximum of that? Or is there as an easier way? I am trying to simplify this for you.

Comment: That is exactly what how is.

Comment: I mean the number of occurences of <account_info_total> is based on the count of each of the tree and then take the maximum.

Comment: Hi Michael, in some cases there are some elements at the end of the input file, like : <subs_base_info></subs_base_info> and <subs_overview_info><subs_overview_info>, they do not appear after executing the xslt. What must be changed in order to keep them in the result? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the names of these elements are known in advance, you can handle them in the same way as `<acct_id>` `<and account_meta_data_info>` are handled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes but when I put "acct_id | account_meta_data_info | subs_base_info | subs_overview_info", then the result of the grouping is at the bottom of the ouput. The result must be in the same place as before grouping. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, do them separately: one group before calling the named template, the other group after.

Comment: I tested this, but must be wrong:

Comment: Michael, I put the xslt I tested in the Original question. I must have done mistake, the result is a never ending loop....

Comment: @ludoaerts **1.** Your input XML is invalid.  **2.** See the addendum to my answer.  **3.** If you have any more questions or comments, please post them immediately below my answer, so that I get notified.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this is working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="account_info">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="acct_id | account_meta_data_info"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="aggregate"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="aggregate">
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= count(account_plan) or $i &lt;= count(account_service) or $i &lt;= count(account_option)">
        <account_info_total_list>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="account_plan[$i] | account_service[$i] | account_option[$i]"/>
        </account_info_total_list>
        <xsl:call-template name="aggregate">
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit:

To match your example output, you need to add one more template:

```
<xsl:template match="account_plan | account_service | account_option">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

### Addendum:

To process the `<subs_base_info>` and `<subs_overview_info>` elements at the end of the input, try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="account_info">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="acct_id | account_meta_data_info"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="aggregate"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="subs_base_info |subs_overview_info"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="aggregate">
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= count(account_plan) or $i &lt;= count(account_service) or $i &lt;= count(account_option)">
        <account_info_total_list>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="account_plan[$i] | account_service[$i] | account_option[$i]"/>
        </account_info_total_list>
        <xsl:call-template name="aggregate">
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="account_plan | account_service | account_option">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This solves the question completely, Thanks Michael!